# GeoFire - Save item to specific location with radius

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geolocation, geofire

I don't have any code to share at this point, but I'm trying to figure out how to solve my issue.. I was hoping some of you might have some advice.

I'm building an app where I get the user's lat/long from `geolocation` and if they are in an predetermined area with a radius they can post data to the server, but not if they aren't in an area that I specified is allowed.. Here is an image for example:

[image]

So in this example, the user could post if they are in the radius of one of the circles but not if they aren't.

I would also have to fetch the data based off of which circle they are in..

What I'm wondering is, how would I specify where these radius' exist and does this scale easily? If I needed to add 10-30 new locations would that be easy to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the user location from the device and as you have the circles; you have the circle centre with their radius. At time of posting, you check the distance from the user location to the circle centre and enumerate thought the circle locations. if the distance is within the radius, they can post if not, not.

```
var radius = 100 //example

let canPostLocations = [
    CLLocation1,
    CLLocation2
]

func isInRange() -> Bool {
    for canPost in canPostLocations {
        let locationDistance = location.distance(from: canPost)
        if (locationDistance < radius) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

use as:

```
var mayPost = false
var userLocation: CLLocation! = nil

if userLocation != nil {
    mayPost = InRange(location: userLocation).isInRange()
}
```